# Mysql After Update/İnsert Triggers and 1442-Error

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1442

I want to see new records and updates entered in the log table, I created a trigger for this but I get error 1442. Can you help me, please?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_changes`
    AFTER UPDATE ON `customers`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    Update customers c INNER JOIN cust_changes ch ON ch.id = c.id SET ch.name = c.name
```

1442 - Can't update table 'cust_changes' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: The error is pretty clear and there is no way round it. If you can explain what you are trying to do someone may be able to suggest an alternative. Note in a before update query you can amend NEW. values.

Comment: When some data in the Customers table is updated, I would like to see the updated data in the cust_changes table.Or if you have a better solution, please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the data in the trigger using the pseudo table name OLD or NEW.

```
Update cust_changes
SET name = NEW.name
WHERE id=NEW.id
```

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Can you post the update statement that fires the trigger?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_changes`
    AFTER UPDATE ON `customers`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    Update customers c INNER JOIN cust_changes ch ON ch.id = c.id SET ch.name = c.name

Comment: Not the trigger DDL. The UPDATE statement that caused this trigger fired.

Answer (score 0):

If you use OLD.id (or NEW.id) in the updated statement then mysql (as @PeterHe) suggested is happy. If your model is different or you are doing something different then you need to tell us.

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t(id int, name varchar(3));
create table t1(id int,name varchar(3));

insert into t values(1,null);
insert into t1 values(1,null);

CREATE TRIGGER t
    AFTER UPDATE ON t
    FOR EACH ROW 
    Update t INNER JOIN t1  ON t1.id = old.id 
        SET t1.name = t.name;

update t set name = ('aaa');

select * from t1;

+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | aaa  |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As expected with no errors. Please add your versions for mysql and phpmyadmin.